# Magento 2 Duplicate product does not work

Tags: magento2, server-setup

I use Magento 2.3 and for the same of product when I use **save** and **duplicate** the server does not respond.
I think this is a server problem and my question is,
What is the best config for Magento 2 and best config on **php.ini** or **apache.conf** or **nginx.conf**?

Answer (score 1):

There was a known issue with this duplicate feature:
 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4096

Check your version